# PHP Radio button automatically that clicked before clear after clicking previous

Tags: php, html

I am facing the problem with the radio button, that is automatically cleared when I click the previous button and it not submitting to a database.I unable to match this with the answer in the database. And the same problem with button next button also i am getting.

```
enter code here
<div class="container question">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-7 ">
                    <p>
                    Online exam 
                    </p>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="well">
                    <div id="replace_question">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id='login' method="post" action="result.php">

                        <?php
                        $number_question = $_POST['num_questions'];
                        $row = mysqli_query( $con, "select * from questions where category_id=$category ORDER BY RAND()");
                        $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows( $row );
                        $remainder = $rowcount/$number_question;
                        $i = 0;
                        $j = 1; $k = 1;
                        ?>
                        <?php while ( $result = mysqli_fetch_array($row) ) {
                             if ( $i == 0) echo "<div class='cont' id='question_splitter_$j'>";?>
                            <div id='question<?php echo $k;?>' >
                            <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $j;?>"> <?php echo $k?>.<?php echo $result['question_name'];?></p>
                            <?php if (isset($result['answer1'])){?>
                            <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['answer1'];?>
                            <br/>
                            <?php }?>
                            <?php if(isset($result['answer2'])) {?>
                            <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['answer2'];?>
                            <br/>
                            <?php }?>
                            <?php if(isset($result['answer3'])){?>
                            <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['answer3'];?>
                            <br/>
                            <?php }?>
                            <?php if(isset($result['answer4'])){?>
                            <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['answer4'];?>
                            <br/>
                            <?php }?>
                            <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>                                                                      
                            <br/>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                            break;


                             } ?>   
                             </div>
                             </div>
                            </form>
                             <hr>
                             <input type="hidden" name="cur_ques_no" id="cur_ques_no" value="1">
                             <button id="1" class='previous btn btn-primary' type="button">Previous</button>
                             <button id="1" class="next btn btn-primary" type="button">Next</button>

                             </div>
                             </div>
                             </div>
```

How do i solve this issue please help me with this below code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.